# Lua insert statement

Tags: mysql, lua, luasql

I'm having problems with my insert statement:

```lua
Create = function (LN,FN,Add,Tel,Cell)
    LastName = tostring(LN);
    FirstName = tostring(FN);
    Address = tostring(Add);
    Telephone =tostring(Tel); 
    Cellphone = tostring(Cell);
```

--source of the problem

```lua
conn:execute([[INSERT INTO book(LastName, FirstName, Address, Telephone, Cellphone) VALUES ("]]"'"LastName"','"FirstName"','" Address"','" Telephone"','" Cellphone")]]'")

 print ("\n Creating an account Successful")
 end
```

Comment: `conn:execute([[INSERT INTO book(LastName, FirstName, Address, Telephone, Cellphone) VALUES (']]..LastName.."','"..FirstName.."','"..Address.."','"..Telephone.."','"..Cellphone.."')")`

Comment: Please look into prepared statements and data binding. String concatenation is less efficient and leads to injection attacks.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest that you use the [`string.format`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.format) for placing the data:

```lua
Create = function (LN,FN,Add,Tel,Cell)
    local LastName, FirstName, Address, Telephone, Cellphone = tostring(LN), tostring(FN), tostring(Add), =tostring(Tel), tostring(Cell)
    local sQuery = [[INSERT INTO book(LastName, FirstName, Address, Telephone, Cellphone) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')]]
    conn:execute( sQuery:format(LastName, FirstName, Address, Telephone, Cellphone) )
```

Comment: You might want to correct the typo on sQeury in the conn:execute